VSCode autocomplete for javascript destructured parameters
I have javascript.suggest.completeFunctionCalls=true
function aaa(a, b, c) {
    return [a, b, c]
}

function bbb({ a, b, c }) {
    return [a, b, c]
}

Autocomplete works as expected for aaa with TAB or ENTER


Autocomplete doesn't work for bbb, it results in an empty function instead
How can I configure vsc to solve this?


